# Div set to 80%. I want the span to be 100% of that div. How do I do that?

Tags: css, html

So I have a div that's set to 80% width. I then have a span inside of that div, that I would like to set to 100% width of it's outside div. The third span takes up an x% of the second span.

```
<div>
    <span>
        <span></span>                             
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm looking to do this for my portfolio website @ vadimp.com

In the 'Services' section, you'll see blue bars indicating my 'percentage' of knowledge for the specific skills (CSS, HTML, Photoshop), I want those blue bars (`span class=barBk`) to take up the entire width of the div.

I've tried setting `barBk` to 100% width and display:inline-block but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use some `display:inline-block` or `display:block` to give to your *inline*  a width ;-)

You should think about that syntax if your code allows it:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <span></span>
        <!-- something else -->
    </div>
</div>
```